# How to extract an object from a json response and store it in a var with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I get this response in the console and I want to store the "text" part to a variable using jQuery or JS. It gets logged as console.log(response);

[image: Console Reponse (JSON)]

Comment: `response.generations[0].text` ?

Comment: @David - I got this back when I did that - VM698:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: If `response` is not defined than how can `console.log(response)` produce this output?  Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @David - the response is 100% coming through. It may be something I've done In the code below...        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            var resolve = response.generations[0].text;
        });

Comment: In that context, `response` is most certainly defined.  It sounds like you're making a mistake or false assumption somewhere in your debugging.  Without a [mcve] there isn't much we can do.

Comment: @David just tried var text = response["generations"][0]["text"]; and it worked! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = response["generations"][0]["text"];
```